# Re-ordering legend labels for 3 geom_smooth's on same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, legend

I've been staring at solutions for the past couple of hours but can't find an analogous one that clicks. I am trying to simply rearrange the legend title for plot with 3 geom_smooth's. My dataframe has 3 columns as separate lines, and they are all plotted in relation to the 4th column. To simplify, I created a very small data frame:

```
x <- data.frame("Score" = c(2,4,7,3,2,1,5,6,4,3,1,3), "var1" = c(3,4,3,6,7,6,4,3,5,7,7,3), "var2" = c(3,5,6,5,2,3,7,8,4,3,6,1))
x

ggplot(data = x)+
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Score, y=var1 , linetype = "var1"), color = "black", se = FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Score, y=var2, linetype = "var2"), colour = "black", se = FALSE)+
  scale_x_discrete()+
  scale_y_discrete()
```

In this example, I just want to move the "y at Age 13-18" below the other label. To clarify, both lines on this plot are on the same scale (y).

Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

**Edit.**

New code posted by the OP in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501546/re-ordering-legend-labels-for-3-geom-smooths-on-same-plot#comment99592185_56501546).

```
x <- data.frame("Score" = c(2,4,7,3,2,1,5,6,4,3,1,3), 
                "Age_6to10" = c(3,4,3,6,7,6,4,3,5,7,7,3), 
                "Age_13to18" = c(3,5,6,5,2,3,7,8,4,3,6,1))

x

ggplot(data = x) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Score, y= Age_6to10 , linetype = "y at Age 6-10"), color = "black", se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Score, y=Age_13to18, linetype = "y at Age 13-18"), colour = "black", se = FALSE)+ 
  scale_x_discrete() + 
  scale_y_discrete(name= "y")
```

Comment: My apologies, this is the correct code:                                                                         x <- data.frame("Score" = c(2,4,7,3,2,1,5,6,4,3,1,3), "Age_6to10" = c(3,4,3,6,7,6,4,3,5,7,7,3), "Age_13to18" = c(3,5,6,5,2,3,7,8,4,3,6,1))
x

ggplot(data = x)+
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Score, y= Age_6to10 , linetype = "y at Age 6-10"), color = "black", se = FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Score, y=Age_13to18, linetype = "y at Age 13-18"), colour = "black", se = FALSE)+
  scale_x_discrete()+
  scale_y_discrete(name= "y")

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56501546/edit) button instead.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice with ggplot is to reshape your data so each of the characteristics you want to appear in a legend and which you want to map to an aesthetic (say, linetype) are put into a column. In this case I use `tidyr::gather` to pull the values of the two age groups into one column, and the specification of which group into another column.

```
ggplot(data = tidyr::gather(x, group, value, -Score)) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Score, y= value , 
                            linetype = forcats::fct_rev(group)),
                            color = "black", se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete() + 
  scale_y_discrete(name= "y") +  
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Age group")
```

[image]
Here's how the reshaped data looks:

```
> tidyr::gather(x, group, value, -Score)
   Score      group value
1      2  Age_6to10     3
2      4  Age_6to10     4
3      7  Age_6to10     3
4      3  Age_6to10     6
5      2  Age_6to10     7
6      1  Age_6to10     6
7      5  Age_6to10     4
8      6  Age_6to10     3
9      4  Age_6to10     5
10     3  Age_6to10     7
11     1  Age_6to10     7
12     3  Age_6to10     3
13     2 Age_13to18     3
14     4 Age_13to18     5
15     7 Age_13to18     6
16     3 Age_13to18     5
17     2 Age_13to18     2
18     1 Age_13to18     3
19     5 Age_13to18     7
20     6 Age_13to18     8
21     4 Age_13to18     4
22     3 Age_13to18     3
23     1 Age_13to18     6
24     3 Age_13to18     1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to reformat the data from wide to long, then plot it.
The labels are in the requested order since after reformatting the `variable` is a factor with levels by the correct order. See the output of `str` below.

```
xlong <- reshape2::melt(x, id.vars = "Score")
str(xlong)
#'data.frame':  24 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Score   : num  2 4 7 3 2 1 5 6 4 3 ...
# $ variable: Factor w/ 2 levels "Age_6to10","Age_13to18": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ value   : num  3 4 3 6 7 6 4 3 5 7 ...


ggplot(data = xlong,
       mapping = aes(x = Score, y = value, linetype = variable)) +
  geom_smooth(color = "black", se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete() + 
  scale_y_discrete(name= "y")
```

[image]